# Setting Permission and switch

Tags: ios, flutter, user-permissions

I am trying to create a setting page. In it, I would like to have several switches. The user will use them to manage the Permissions, for Camera, Micro and more.
Here is the code I have written, but clearly something is wrong as it is not working properly.
When I am trying to get the IOS permission, I am only getting false, even if in the IOS settings, the permission is on. I have also edited the info.plist file.
Please, can you advise? Thank you.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:settings_ui/settings_ui.dart';

class PermissionsSettingsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const PermissionsSettingsPage({super.key});

  @override
 State<PermissionsSettingsPage> createState() => _PermissionsSettingsPageState();
}

class _PermissionsSettingsPageState extends State<PermissionsSettingsPage> {
  var _cameraPermissionGranted ;
  var _microphonePermissionGranted ;
  var _contactPermissionGranted;
  var _notificationsPermissionGranted;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkPermissions();
  }

  void _checkPermissions() async {
    final cameraStatus = await Permission.camera.status.isGranted;
    final microphoneStatus = await Permission.microphone.status.isGranted;
    final contactStatus = await Permission.contacts.status.isGranted;
    final notificationStatus = await Permission.notification.status.isGranted;
    setState(() {

      if (cameraStatus==true) {_cameraPermissionGranted = true;}
      if (microphoneStatus==true) {_microphonePermissionGranted = true;}
      if (contactStatus==true) {_contactPermissionGranted = true;}
      if (notificationStatus==true) {_notificationsPermissionGranted = true;}

      // _cameraPermissionGranted = cameraStatus.isGranted;

     // _microphonePermissionGranted = microphoneStatus.isGranted;
    });
  }

  void _requestPermission(Permission permission) async {
    final status = await permission.request();
    if (status.isGranted) {
      setState(() {
        if (permission == Permission.camera) {
          _cameraPermissionGranted = true;
        } else if (permission == Permission.microphone) {
          _microphonePermissionGranted = true;
        }
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Permissions'),
      ),
      body: SettingsList(
        sections: [
          SettingsSection(
            title: const Text('Permissions'),
            tiles: [
              SettingsTile.switchTile(
                title: const Text('Camera'),
                leading: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                initialValue: _cameraPermissionGranted,
                onToggle: (value) {
                  /*if (_cameraPermissionGranted) {
                    _requestPermission(Permission.camera);
                  } else {
                    openAppSettings();
                  }*/
                },
              ),
              SettingsTile.switchTile(
                title: const Text('Microphone'),
                leading: const Icon(Icons.mic),
                initialValue: _microphonePermissionGranted,
                onToggle: (value) {
                  /*if (_microphonePermissionGranted) {
                    _requestPermission(Permission.microphone);
                  } else {
                    openAppSettings();
                  }*/
                },
              ),

              SettingsTile.switchTile(
                title: const Text('Contacts'),
                leading: const Icon(Icons.contacts),
                initialValue: _contactPermissionGranted,
                onToggle: (value) {
                  /*if (_microphonePermissionGranted) {
                    _requestPermission(Permission.microphone);
                  } else {
                    openAppSettings();
                  }*/
                },
              ),

              SettingsTile.switchTile(
                title: const Text('Notification'),
                leading: const Icon(Icons.notifications),
                initialValue: _notificationsPermissionGranted,
                onToggle: (value) {
                  /*if (_microphonePermissionGranted) {
                    _requestPermission(Permission.microphone);
                  } else {
                    openAppSettings();
                  }*/
                },
              ),

            ],
          ),
          SettingsSection(
            title: const Text('Settings'),
            tiles: [
              SettingsTile(
                title: const Text('App Settings'),
                leading: const Icon(Icons.settings),
                onPressed: (_) {
                  openAppSettings();
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem that you ever `_requestPermission()`. These calls are commented out in each of the Tiles, but even there it seems incorrect.

You do:

```
if (_microphonePermissionGranted) {
  _requestPermission(Permission.microphone);
```

But that does not seem to be correct. If `granted` then there's no need to request a permission. Instead you should request a permission first to get it `granted`.

Your code only supports two cases: "granted" and "denied". But I think you need to support the third one "unknown".

Check the docs for all the possible values: [PermissionStatus class](https://pub.dev/documentation/clone_permission_handler/latest/permission_handler/PermissionStatus-class.html).

When you first open the settings page, and if you have never requested the access, then it's "undetermined". If undetermined, you show a button to request it. After requested, the status should become either granted or declined (or other statuses). If granted, we're good. If declined you want these buttons to navigate the user to the App Settings.

```
class _PermissionsSettingsPageState extends State<PermissionsSettingsPage> {
  var _cameraStatus;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkPermissions();
  }

  void _checkPermissions() async {
    setState(() {
      _cameraStatus = Permission.camera.status;
      // I don't think await is needed here since
      //   checking the status should not be async.
      //
      // You'd also want to store the full status
      //   because isGranted only has two states and
      //   it does not support "undetermined".
    });
  }

  PermissionStatus _togglePermission(Permission permission) async {
    final status = permission.status;
    switch (status) {
      case PermissionStatus.unknown:
        return await permission.request();
      case PermissionStatus.granted:
        // no work needed
        break;

      case PermissionStatus.denied:
        openAppSettings();
        break

      case PermissionStatus.disabled:
        // should be unreachable
        break;

      case PermissionStatus.restricted:
        // disabled by iOS policies like MDM,
        //   parental control, privacy settings, etc
        //
        // You might want to show a special message
        //   in that case.
        break;
    }
    return status;
  }

              SettingsTile.switchTile(
                title: const Text('Camera'),
                leading: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                initialValue: _cameraStatus.isGranted,
                onToggle: (value) {
                  setState({
                    _cameraStatus = _togglePermission(Permission.camera);
                  })
                },
```

Finally I don't find using "switch" control applicable here. Yes, you can turn it "on" by requesting a permission, but in fact you can't switch it back to "off" state. So it's just one-way interaction, a button to request the permission should do better here.

Comment: ... I am not a dart expert, in fact I've never ever used it so the code might not work as is. But hopefully you still find it useful and get some insights.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried but I am getting an error message. The switch expect a const for case. I will try to solve this an will update you.